# Why is Keyguard not being Re-enabled?

Tags: android, keyguard

I have a Service that does background video recording, during which time I disable the Keyguard. When I want to stop recording I stop the service and OnDestroy() is called.

I can see in my trace that `ReenableKeyguard()` is called. However, the Keyguard is still disabled until I "Force Stop" the host app that starts the Service.

What could be causing the Keyguard from staying disabled when `ReenableKeyguard()` is called?

This is the code that destroys the Service and Reenables the keyguard. (It's C#/Xamarin but basically the same as Java)

```
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        Tracer.Trace("BackgroundVideoRecorder::OnDestroy();");
        base.OnDestroy();

        try
        {
            camera.Reconnect();
            mediaRecorder.Stop();
            mediaRecorder.Reset();

            camera.StopPreview();
            mediaRecorder.Release();

            camera.Release();
            camera = null;

            if (Common.KeyGuardLocker != null)
            {
                Tracer.Trace("BackgroundVideoRecorder::OnDestroy() - ReenableKeyguard()");
                Common.KeyGuardLocker.ReenableKeyguard();
            }

            windowManager.RemoveView(surfaceView);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Tracer.Trace(ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
I have the exact same problem and the reason was that i had only permissions to Disable keyguard and not the ones to re-enable it.
```

android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD
android.permission.ENABLE_KEYGUARD